# "Failed to compile main.c!" (Trying to install Angband)

Tags: compiling, games, make

Noob here. Tried to install Angband 4.0.5 (rephial.org) but I couldn't `make` it work.

What did I do wrong? I uninstalled an earlier version before this, could there be some old files messing it up?

```
make
 Entering directory src.
cat: ../version: No such file or directory
cat: ../version: No such file or directory
cat: ../version: No such file or directory
cat: ../version: No such file or directory
Successfully generated dependencies.
cat: ../version: No such file or directory
Successfully compiled cave.c.
Successfully compiled cave-map.c.
Successfully compiled cave-square.c.
Successfully compiled cave-view.c.
Successfully compiled cmd-cave.c.
Successfully compiled cmd-core.c.
Successfully compiled cmd-misc.c.
Successfully compiled cmd-obj.c.
Successfully compiled cmd-pickup.c.
Successfully compiled debug.c.
Successfully compiled effects.c.
Successfully compiled game-event.c.
Successfully compiled game-input.c.
Successfully compiled game-world.c.
Successfully compiled generate.c.
Successfully compiled gen-cave.c.
Successfully compiled gen-chunk.c.
Successfully compiled gen-monster.c.
Successfully compiled gen-room.c.
Successfully compiled gen-util.c.
Successfully compiled grafmode.c.
Successfully compiled guid.c.
Successfully compiled init.c.
Successfully compiled load.c.
Successfully compiled message.c.
Successfully compiled mon-attack.c.
Successfully compiled mon-blow-effects.c.
Successfully compiled mon-blow-methods.c.
Successfully compiled mon-desc.c.
Successfully compiled mon-init.c.
Successfully compiled mon-list.c.
Successfully compiled mon-lore.c.
Successfully compiled mon-make.c.
Successfully compiled mon-move.c.
Successfully compiled mon-msg.c.
Successfully compiled mon-power.c.
Successfully compiled mon-spell.c.
Successfully compiled mon-summon.c.
Successfully compiled mon-timed.c.
Successfully compiled mon-util.c.
Successfully compiled obj-chest.c.
Successfully compiled obj-desc.c.
Successfully compiled obj-gear.c.
Successfully compiled obj-identify.c.
Successfully compiled obj-ignore.c.
Successfully compiled obj-info.c.
Successfully compiled obj-list.c.
Successfully compiled obj-make.c.
Successfully compiled obj-pile.c.
Successfully compiled obj-power.c.
Successfully compiled obj-properties.c.
Successfully compiled obj-randart.c.
Successfully compiled obj-slays.c.
Successfully compiled obj-tval.c.
Successfully compiled obj-util.c.
Successfully compiled option.c.
Successfully compiled parser.c.
Successfully compiled randname.c.
Successfully compiled player-attack.c.
Successfully compiled player-birth.c.
Successfully compiled player-calcs.c.
Successfully compiled player-class.c.
Successfully compiled player-history.c.
Successfully compiled player-path.c.
Successfully compiled player-quest.c.
Successfully compiled player-race.c.
Successfully compiled player-spell.c.
Successfully compiled player-timed.c.
Successfully compiled player-util.c.
Successfully compiled player.c.
Successfully compiled project.c.
Successfully compiled project-feat.c.
Successfully compiled project-mon.c.
Successfully compiled project-obj.c.
Successfully compiled project-player.c.
Successfully compiled score.c.
Successfully compiled save.c.
Successfully compiled savefile.c.
Successfully compiled store.c.
Successfully compiled target.c.
Successfully compiled trap.c.
Successfully compiled ui-birth.c.
Successfully compiled ui-command.c.
Successfully compiled ui-context.c.
Successfully compiled ui-death.c.
Successfully compiled ui-display.c.
Successfully compiled ui-event.c.
Successfully compiled ui-game.c.
Successfully compiled ui-help.c.
Successfully compiled ui-history.c.
Successfully compiled ui-init.c.
Successfully compiled ui-input.c.
Successfully compiled ui-keymap.c.
Successfully compiled ui-knowledge.c.
Successfully compiled ui-map.c.
Successfully compiled ui-menu.c.
Successfully compiled ui-mon-list.c.
Successfully compiled ui-mon-lore.c.
Successfully compiled ui-obj-list.c.
Successfully compiled ui-object.c.
Successfully compiled ui-options.c.
Successfully compiled ui-output.c.
Successfully compiled ui-player.c.
Successfully compiled ui-prefs.c.
Successfully compiled ui-score.c.
Successfully compiled ui-signals.c.
Successfully compiled ui-spell.c.
Successfully compiled ui-store.c.
Successfully compiled ui-target.c.
Successfully compiled ui-term.c.
Successfully compiled wiz-debug.c.
Successfully compiled wiz-spoil.c.
Successfully compiled wiz-stats.c.
Successfully compiled buildid.c.
Successfully compiled z-bitflag.c.
Successfully compiled z-color.c.
Successfully compiled z-dice.c.
Successfully compiled z-expression.c.
Successfully compiled z-file.c.
Successfully compiled z-form.c.
Successfully compiled z-quark.c.
Successfully compiled z-queue.c.
Successfully compiled z-rand.c.
Successfully compiled z-set.c.
Successfully compiled z-textblock.c.
Successfully compiled z-type.c.
Successfully compiled z-util.c.
Successfully compiled z-virt.c.
      LINK angband.o           
main.c:50:1: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]
 {
 ^
main.c:49:28: error: zero or negative size array ‘modules’
 static const struct module modules[] =
                            ^
Failed to compile main.c!
../mk/buildsys.mk:242: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make[3]: *** [main.o] Error 1
../mk/buildsys.mk:110: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
mk/buildsys.mk:115: recipe for target 'subdirs' failed
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 2
mk/buildsys.mk:110: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

P.S.: Does anyone know how to make a block quote scrollable so it doesn't take up so much space?

Comment: You use code formatting, not block quote, for command output (select text and press Ctrl-K)